# Will a browser keep a permanent redirect alive in cache if the page is revisited?

Tags: browser, redirection, cache

Erroneously a permanent redirect was made to a server for a few hours. For unknown reasons the server can't make a redirect back so now everyone who visited the web-page in these hours can't access the page without clearing the cache.
Now, we can't know who these people are and inform them why the page doesn't appear or what they would need to do to make it work again. Hence, there is nothing to do but wait for the permanent redirect to exit these peoples cache.

My question: If they visit the page again before the redirect is pushed out of the cache will it then be put back to the beginning of queue of cached pages thus keeping the cache alive?

Background if you find this weird:
We had a company make our web-page (just a plain web-page and not our products which is a service).
Apparently their server was not ready even though they told us to make our A-DNS-records for foo.com point to their server. Therefore they haphazardly made their server redirect to the staging version of the address (foo.com -> foo.staging.com) because the staging version was still on the staging server at the time.
I've told them to make a redirect back to the actual server from the staging server for (foo.stading.com -> foo.com), but they say that their staging server (which is shared between many clients) can't do that. - That is of course ridiculous.

Comment: in my experience, it would. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431164/cannot-remove-301-redirect

Comment: @SathyajithBhat That's what I'm expecting. Any good cache would.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a tad confused you talk about a permanent redirect (HTTP 301 error) but then say that it's a DNS A record that's directing people to the server.

For DNS the record will exist until it's time to live (handed out by the DNS server) is met or until the user clears their cache. If they visit before that change is made then yes the TTL will be reset.

For an HTTP 301 the answer is it depends, once the 301 redirect is cached then the browser won't actually check the original page. It will simply go to the redirect page.

Comment: So a DNS A record for foo.com was changed to point to a server. That is fine.
However, on that server a permanent redirect was then made to foo.bar.com.

Comment: I see. Do people need to go to the server normally? Since it's a staging server it seems like the simplest solution would be to make the A record point to the correct location and remove the 301 from the staging server. Have the developers (or whomever works on the staging server) clear their browser cache after the 301 has been removed.

Comment: So the problem is that we changed foo.com to go to their server and that their server permanently redirected people to foo.bar.com. That means it was out in the wild for hours. The reason they redirected to the staging server is that they had forgotten to put it on the "real" server, and that was of course a mistake.

I cannot know which people in the world visited the site in those hours.
Right now anybody who visited foo.com in those hours are send to foo.staging.com by their browser because of the permanent redirect.
A-record points to the correct place: Their real server (not staging).

Comment: While not an elegant approach, if you put a 302 (temporary redirect) on foo.bar.com to redirect back to foo.com that should force the browser to recheck foo.com and see if the 301 is still there. This of course means that foo.bar.com will be unreachable for a short time while the 302 is there and while it's TTL is active

Comment: That's what I suggested (although I suggested a permanent redirect). But as I said they say they can't do that. Which I say is ridiculous.

Comment: They put a 301 in so they should be able to put the 302 in

Comment: The 301 was put on the actual server while I now need a 301/302 on the staging server. I agree that it makes no sense. I will of course fight them on this again.